# What is the meaning of "based as it is"?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

I can hardly say I understood the sentence as a whole but the most complex part for me to get is the one with "based as it is."

The sentence:

> The distinction between activity and passivity as well as that between mediated and unmediated communication falls well within the interactive paradigm, **based as it is** on the face-to-face or ‘transmission’ analogue for communication.

Source: Communication Theory by David Holmes

Comment: The phrase you are after is "based as it is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"based as it is on" is a fancy way of saying "as it is based on", which just means "because it is based on". It would be clearer if it were written as it is spoken: "based, as it is, on".